# R - List factor levels by group

Tags: r, unique

I have a large dataset which has the following format:

```
Unit     ZoneCode  
2119601  R1Z    
2119601  R1Z  
2119601  B1Z  
2119602  PUZ2  
2119602  R1Z
```

I would like to produce output that lists - for each unit - each unique ZoneCode that is associated with that Unit.

The output would look like this

```
Unit     ZoneCode  
2119601  R1Z  
2119602  PUZ2  
2119602  R1Z
```

I would appreciate assistance with R Code to do this

Comment: I have trouble understanding what you're trying to achieve. Shouldn't `2119601 B1Z` also be in the desired output? If you just want to delete duplicate rows in that dataset, have a look at `?duplicated`.

Comment: @Graham  Why don't you have `2119601 BIZ` in the expected output.  Try `unique(dat)`

Answer (score 0):

The R function that produces a unique list is unique(df)

Thanks to @akrun